# Login without redirect Auth0 on SPA

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, auth0

I'm implementing Auth0 in my SPA app, one of the requeriments is to have a custom UI, that also implies that i cannot use redirects to the Universal Login Page of Auth0.

After reading throught the Auth0 website, i found the Resource Owner grant type, which seems to solve my problem to handle a login directly using Auth0 API.

Is there any drawbacks of using this grant type?? (I read that is not very recommended, but i wanna hear opnions about this)

Also, is there any alternative to this grant type?? I mean, i'm stuck with this solution if Biz doesn't want redirections?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Resource Owner Password Grant**

This can sometimes be a useful 'bridging solution', but it has some disadvantages as summarised in [this article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications) from a couple of years ago. These are perhaps the main downsides:

- Single Sign On across apps won't work
- Federated login options won't work (Integrated Windows / 2 Factor)
- Security reviews may perform less well

**Redirecting for Logins**

It is very standard to redirect users to login, which signifies that you are externalising security to an expert provider. Most systems do this, including Gmail and Office 365:

- You start at mail.google.com
- For logins you are redirected to accounts.google.com
- You then return to mail.google.com

My [blog page](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/) shows the login redirect user experience for Web / Desktop / Mobile apps and there is an SPA there which you can run.

Of course, if your app is well coded there should be no down side to redirects. Eg the app should maintain the user location within your SPA, and also any data the user is editing.